# jquery ui selectable combined with draggable works in IE but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, draggable, selectable

I have a tree of resources which is set up as a table, and I want to be able to select a number of resources from the tree using Ctrl-Click to select multiple resources and drag them over onto a table of jobs to allocate resources to a job.

This all works well in IE8. but when I try it in Firefox, selection doesn't work at all, when I disable the draggable then selectable works Ok, so its obviously a conflict between draggable and selectable that only occurs in Firefox.

Using Firebug it appears that _mouseStart is not fired when clicking on one of the table cells, but it is if you click on some area of the table which is not a cell.

I've set up a test page is to demonstrate the issue here: [www.qualitech.co.nz/test.aspx](http://www.qualitech.co.nz/test.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The only reason this works at all is because of a coding error in IE that allows a position CSS rule to apply to TD elements. According to W3C conventions, inner table elements must always be rendered with position: static. In order for draggable to function, the draggable element must be able to be removed from document flow with a non-static position. This is not possible for TD elements. Consider switching to an unordered list and making your list items selectable and draggable.